# need to insert cart details into Mysql database using Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, vue.js

i have a question about how can i insert my cart details into my database with Laravel. i got request data like this.

```
cart: [
  0: {
   product: {
    product_id: 1,
    product_name: "Item One"
   },
   quantity: 4   
 },
 1: {
   product: {
    product_id: 2,
    product_name: "Item two"
   },
   quantity: 7   
 }
]
```

i need to add these data into Mysql database using Laravel controller. i have no idea with writing controller function to manage these data with auto generated unique order_id. i got this array from my front end VueJs code.
Can anyone help me for this?

my request->all() data looks like this

```
array:1 [
  "{"cart":" => array:1 [
    "{"product":{"id":1,"category":1,"product_name":"Brinjal 500g","product_image":"1585409454.jpeg","product_price":232,"unit":"500g","product_description":null,"stock":"In Stock","product_status":1,"show":1,"delievery_date":null,"vendor":null,"quantity":18,"item_type":"feature_product","created_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:54.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:54.000000Z","deleted_at":null,"categories":{"id":1,"category_name":"Fresh Fruits","category_image":null,"category_description":null,"category_status":1,"show":0,"created_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:12.000000Z","updated_at":"2020-03-28T15:30:12.000000Z","deleted_at":null}},"quantity":1}" => null
  ]
]
```

Comment: what is your database structure. can you share that also so that we can get more idea.

Comment: i have no idea about making a structure. but i only need to insert product_id, product_name, quantity in same table

Comment: are you getting data in json format?

Answer (score 0):

To insert data:

```
Model::create($data);
```

To update data:

```
Model::where('id', $id)->update($data);
```

Comment: how can i get that data to my query colums in controller function

Comment: $OrderPro = new Ordersproducts;
    $OrderPro->order_id = $order_id;
    $OrderPro->product_id = $data['product_id'];

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your data coming and make array as below i have shown.

Try this one by creating the array of the data and insert array to the database as bulk data:

```
// this will decode your json data that you're getting in the post data
$postdata = json_decode($postdata, true);

$data = [];
foreach ($postdata as $key => $value) {        
    $data[$key]['product_id'] = $value['product']['id'];
    $data[$key]['product_name'] = $value['product']['product_name'];
    $data[$key]['quantity'] = $value['quantity'];
}

// $data now will have data as following structure

$data = [[
    'product_id' => 2,
    'product_name' => "Item two",
    'quantity' => 7   

],
[
    'product_id' => 2,
    'product_name' => "Item two",
    'quantity' => 7   

]];

$order = Order::create($data);
```

Comment: how can i make my cart array like this sorting

Comment: @K.Mihiranga i have updated the answer pls. have a look into it.

Comment: i updated my code like above. ($postdata = json_decode($request->cart, true);) . But it shows me this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: i updated my question above how request data looks like in server

Comment: @K.Mihiranga you can still refer to my solution i have updated it.